# Show div in Image hover?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to get something like the effect you see when you hove the image in this example:  [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-teamer/full_screen_preview/5161985?ref=janecross&ref=janecross&clickthrough_id=171266960&redirect_back=true).

When you hove the image a div is shown over the image, once you mouse-out the div the div is hidden.

The image size is: 920x300

I tried with no luck with:

```
$('.my-img').hover(function(){
    $('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000)
}, function(){
    $('.my-div').animate({left: '-920px'}, 1000)
});
```

More info for css and html:

```
    .my-wrapper{
        position: relative;
    }

    .my-div{
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        height: 300px;
        width: 920px;
        left: -920px;

    }

<div class="my-wrapper">
<div class="my-div">some text here</div>
<img ... /img>
</div>
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle ??

Comment: `.my-div !== .info-cliente` and what about the html structure.

Comment: updated to show css and html

Comment: @chefnelone Your code will work fine, better explain clearly.

Comment: it works but if just you move the pointer over my-div once this is shown this is hidden again , this is wrong. my-div should be hidden when mouse-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a container for my-div

```
<div class="rel-wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/920/300" width="920" height="300" class="my-img">
    <div class="my-div">
        Redbox
    </div>
</div>
```

Set position as relative for container

```
.rel-wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:920px;
    height:300px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

and apply top and left to my-div

```
.my-div{
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        width: 920px;
        height: 300px;
        left: -940px; /*a little far left than the required block*/
        top: 0px;
}
```

I've added a delay of 1 second in the animation(before callback).

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.my-img').hover(function(){
        $('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000)
        }, function(){
        $('.my-div').delay( 1000).animate({left: '-940px'}, 1000)
    });
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/babumxx/Y4wC4/8/

Preview: fiddle.jshell.net/babumxx/Y4wC4/8/show/

You can also do it in two parts. Show on *mouseenter* and hide on *mouseout*

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.my-img').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    });
    $('.my-img').mouseout(function(){
        $('.my-div').delay( 1000).animate({left: '-940px'}, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle here : jsfiddle.net/babumxx/Y4wC4/9/

Since you want to keep the redblock, you can apply mouse out on the container, and this will solve this issue. - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/babumxx/Y4wC4/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.my-img').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.my-div').animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    });

    //Trigger hide, when mouse leaves rel-wrap
    $('.rel-wrap').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.my-div').delay( 1000).animate({left: '-940px'}, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fiddle I see the same problem that I have with my code. Once the my-div is shown you just move the mouse pointer over my-div and you will see that my-div is hidden again. This is wrong, it should be hidden when the pointer moves out.

Comment: Since you want to keep the redblock steady, you may hide my-div on mouse out of the container, and this will solve this issue.  $('.rel-wrap').mouseleave(hide block);

Answer (score 0):

Modify the div css like this and try again:

```
.my-div { position: relative; }
```

Comment: not working, I just updated the question and paste the css I'm using for .my-div right now.

Comment: it works but if just you move the pointer over my-div once this is shown this is hidden again , this is wrong. my-div should be hidden when mouse-out